# Exercise $12$, Section $3.A$ - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, linear-transformations

The previous post was not written correctly. So, I am posting it again with the correct format I originally wanted.

Exercise: Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional with $\dim V >0$, and suppose $W$ is
infinite-dimensional. Prove that $L(V, W)$ is infinite-dimensional.

Proof: Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a basis of $V$. Suppose that $L(V, W)$ is finite dimensional. Then there exist linear maps $T_1,\dots,T_k$ such that for all $S\in L(V, W)$ we have that $S=a_1T_1+\dots+a_kT_k$. Using the theorem that there exists a unique linear map that can take on any value on its basis, we can define many such linear maps $S_j$ for $j\in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that for every $w\in W$ there exists a linear map $S_j$ such that for one fixed vector $v_m$ in the basis of $V$ we have that $S_j(v_m)=w$.

By hypothesis we know that $T_1,\dots,T_k$ spans $L(V, W)$. Thus there exist scalars $a_1,\dots,a_n\in F$ such that $S_j(v_m)=a_1T_1(v_m)+\dots+a_kT_k(v_m)$. Because we have a map $S$ for every $w\in W$ and $T_1(v_m),\dots,T_k(v_m)\in W$. The above representation implies that $T_1(v_m),\dots,T_k(v_m)$ spans $W$. Which is a contradiction as $W$ is infinite dimensional. Hence, $L(V, W)$ is infinite-dimensional.

Is the proof correct?

Edit: Accidentally used the same variable for the length of the basis of $L(V,W)$ that I used for the basis of $V$. Changed the variables now.

Comment: I am not hundred percent sure. But there seems some flaws in the proof.

(1)  If dim $V=n$, then  dim $L(V,W)$ is not necessarily equal to $n$. So we should assume that $L(V,W)$  have a basis $T_1, T_2, ..., T_m$, where $m$ may not be equal to $n$.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung I did write $n$ but I wasn’t thinking about it as the same as the $\dim V$. Are there any other flaws?

Comment: I cannot find any.

Comment: Do you know following result: If $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n\in \Bbb{N}$ and $\mathrm{dim}(W)=m\in \Bbb{N}$, then $\mathrm{dim}(L(V,W))=nm\in \Bbb{N}$. Contrapositive of this result proves your problem.

Comment: @user264745 I was not aware of that result. That works as well!

Comment: @user264745 That’s interesting. This problem is 3 sections before the section about isomorphic vector spaces. So, I was trying to prove it using the theory developed so far. But that sounds like an interesting way of proving the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have made things more complicated than they should be.

As $W$ is infinite-dimensional, for every $m$ there must exists a linearly independent set in $W$ with $m$ elements, lets say $\{w_1, \cdots, w_m\}$.

Let $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$, and define (using the theorem you mention in your solution) $f_i \in L(V,W)$ for $i=1, \cdots, m$ given by $f_i(v_1)=w_i$ and any other vectors of $W$ for the rest of the $v_i$.

Then, $\{f_1, \cdots, f_{m}\}$ is a linearly independent set in $L(V,W)$ of $m$ elements. As $m$ is arbitrary, $L(V,W)$ cannot have finite dimension.

Comment: Can’t believe I didn’t think of that. Thanks!